# WooCommerce - Send monthly emails based on order date

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Heyyo,

So I'm currently maintaining/further developing a Wordpress-based website, which uses WooCommerce to handle orders. The system works by the customer purchasing monthly subscriptions to receive help in various matters, and at the end of the subscription, we'd like to notify the user by email that the subscription has ended (which is currently the issue at hand).

I've had a look at [MailChimp for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-mailchimp/)-plugin(s), but quickly realised that'd make it difficult to make sure the customers receive an email a month after their purchase, and not just at the start of each month. Furthermore, I've had a look at the [WooCommerce-query documentation](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query), which makes it seem possible to make a custom function, get each and every completed order, check if the current date is one month after the purchase, and run PHP's `mail()` function. But I've not given it too much thought and rather just kept it as "an idea".

And as such, I am here. If anyone have any suggestions or ideas, it'd be well appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have done this some month ago...
1. register a wordpress cron [see in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event)
2. in the cron callback get all orders from a date, or an timespan like this:

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'completed',
    'date_paid' => '<' . ( time() - 561600) // for a timespan
    // 'date_paid' => (time() - 561600) for a fixed date
);
$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

[check the documentation here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#date)

3. Loop through orders
4. get the client email-adress from the order

   $order = $order->get_data();
   $mail  = $order['billing']['email'];
5. send your mail. [wp_mail() is your friend](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)